# Deleted tableviewcell gets replaced by last cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, cell

I've got a problem with my tableView that is filled with realm objects. When I delete a cell the last cell of the tableView is jumping into the place of the removed cell. Anybody knows what could be the reason for this behavior?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{

        self.updateModel(at: indexPath)
        self.loadTimes()
    }
}

func loadTimes(){

    results = realm.objects(Times.self)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

 func updateModel(at indexpath: IndexPath) {
    if let itemForDeletion = results?[indexpath.row] {
        do{
            try self.realm.write {
                self.realm.delete(itemForDeletion)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by jumping? Does the table view scroll to unexpected position or what?

Comment: @Mika The last Cell/Row of the tableview is replacing the Cell/Row that got deleted. So not like usual that the next Row to the deleted Row is replacing it, its always the last row of the tableview. First I thought its because the RealmBrowser is doing the same but on other Projects of mine it had no impact on the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm guarantees consistent order of `Results` only when query is sorted. Try adding call to `sorted`

```
results = realm.objects(Times.self)
```

becomes

```
results = realm.objects(Times.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "time")
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are updating(or deleting) then you load your table view in a global thread. Your not using assync methods, so, they are not run in a sequence.
Try to make a let group = DispatchGroup() and before load or delete, do a group.enter() and after it finishes updating(or deleting) you make group.leave() and enter in the next loading method.

But, please, try to make assync methods using closures while inserting or updating realm objects. Separate the responsibilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but unfortunately the tableView is still doing the same